# OMP parallelisation not working in variadic CRTP class

Tags: c++, performance, openmp, crtp

I have a coding problem with a CRTP base class which provides a function that gets called in a loop in the derived class

```
template<typename Derived>
class Func
{
public:
  double func(int i)
  {
    return pow(i + 1, 2.5);
  }
};

template<template<typename> typename... Args>
class Loop : public Args<Loop<Args...>>...
{
public:
  static const size_t N = 100000000;
  std::array<double, N> _array;

  void loop()
  {
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static)
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
      _array[i] = func(i);
    }
  }
};
```

(in this example the crtp isnt needed, but in my code).
Compiling this in Visual Studio 2017 with /MD /MP /O2 /Oi /Ot /fp:precise /D NDEBUG /openmp /GL Flags the loop isn't parallelized, whereas when i let the variadic template away

```
class Loop2 : public Func<Loop<Func>>
{
public:
  static const size_t N = 100000000;
  std::array<double, N> _array;

  void loop()
  {
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static)
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        _array[i] = func(i);
    }
  }
};
```

the loop is running parallel.
Is it possible to maintain the comfort of the variadic template and parallelizing the loop?

Edit: using Clang with Visual Studio as compiler, both loops are parallelized

Comment: That sounds like a compiler issue - have you tried a different one?

Comment: thanks for the hint, thought i was using omp incorrecty, now i will try with another compiler

Comment: can you give use a full compiling sample that skeches the problem? I'd like to test on my Linux box, but I must be sure to have the same setup.

Comment: Here is the code i used to test if the code is running parallel. Compiling this with Visual Studio on my machine, only the second loop is parallelized. https://onlinegdb.com/B1rFsWz9m